# Iam a single man and everyday I ejaculate is it haram or halal?

Tags: masturbation

what should I do anything please tell me

Comment: The question is whether you ejaculate by your own will (masturbation) or unwillingly (wet dreams etc.). Haram or in best case makrooh is when you do it willingly.

Comment: This is a more health concern question not a haram or halal question. you should worry about your health.

Answer (score 0):

Masturbation is haram, doesn't matter if you are single or not. Repent sincerely and try to break this habit. (Also, what is the picture for?)